# How to look up tax schedules using SuiteTalk?

Tags: netsuite

I have the internal id of a tax schedule and I want to look up the name using SuiteTalk.

In NetSuite tax schedules are found at Set up > Accounting > Taxes > Tax Schedules.

The records browser and schema browser don't seem to mention tax schedule, except as a RecordRef field in InventoryItem: https://system.na1.netsuite.com/help/helpcenter/en_US/srbrowser/Browser2014_2/schema/record/inventoryitem.html?mode=package

Answer (score 1):

From NetSuite support:

Thank you for contacting NetSuite Customer Support. At this time, the Tax Schedule is not exposed to SuiteTalk. We do have an Enhancement Request logged for this feature request and it has been updated with your account information and comments. Our Product Management team periodically reviews these Enhancement Requests and perhaps this will be available in a future release.

Enhancement # - 217321

Summary: WS > Expose Tax Schedules through web services